# Karma Jasmine actually routes causing tests with $httpBackend.flush(); to fail

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Basically, I'm porting from one project to another, and a lot of the tests are failing with the following error message:

`Error: Unexpected request: GET /api/v1/foo/getFoobar`

After looking into it, this is the result of the default route loading. Which isn't happening in the original project. I'm guessing it's a configuration issue, but I'm not sure.

I've confirmed that commenting out the "otherwise" route fixes the issue, but then there's not default route.  It might be worth noting, that I'm using angular-router-ui.

It's worth noting, that this will happen with any test, and is exposed when `$httpBackend.flush();` is run.  It doesn't matter what service or modules are loaded.

**karma.config.js**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    var karmaConfig =
    {
        basePath: './',

        files: [
            /* relevant files */
        ],

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        reporters: ['dots' /*, 'coverage'*/],
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        browserNoActivityTimeout: 60000,
        captureTimeout: 60000,
        autoWatch: false,
        singleRun: false,

        plugins: [
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-coverage',
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-spec-reporter',
            'karma-phantomjs-launcher'
        ]

    };
    config.set(karmaConfig);
};
```

**routing.ts**

```
namespace cg.web.client
{
    export interface ICGState extends ng.ui.IState {
        title: string;
    }
}

app.config(($stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider, $urlRouterProvider: ng.ui.IUrlRouterProvider) => {
    $stateProvider.state('standard', { url: "/standard", templateUrl: "client/common/ui/master/standard.html" });

    $stateProvider
        .state('standard.default', {
            templateUrl: 'default/ui/master.html',
            data: { isdefault: true }
        })
        .state('standard.default.home', <cg.web.client.ICGState>{
            templateUrl: 'default/home/ui/main.html',
            url: '/home'
        })
        .state('standard.default.search', <cg.web.client.ICGState>{
            templateUrl: 'default/search/ui/main.html',
            url: '/search/:active'
        })
        .state('standard.default.profile', {
            templateUrl: 'default/ui/master.html',
            data: { isdefault: true }
        })        

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/standard/home');
});
```

Comment: You have a route that goes to your API ?

Comment: Can you post your routing config ?

Comment: Ignore my previous response.  I understand your question now.  No, that api call happens as part of the default route.

Comment: Then you have a condition somewhere that triggers a redirection. Search for `$window.location` calls, maybe ?

Comment: I just checked, nothing.  However, I did add a console.log to get the current href, and it's the phantomjs address `http://localhost:9876/context.html`

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that I've stripped this test to just the flush call, and I'm not injecting any services, factories, or controllers.  I'm just registering the module and calling flush.